# Permission problem in Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

In my application I'm using lame.exe and gs32.exe to convert audio respectively pdfs. On the simulator this works great, but on the SurfaceUnit, I have to verify that I really want to run this programm. This is really annoying, how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

> Open "Internet Options" in IE:
>
> It's under Security setting > Custom
>   Level> "Launching Applications and
>   Unsafe Files".
>
> Check the "Enable" box and the prompts
>   should disappear.

I think it is really weird that the Internet Explorer can do such things in the Operating System.